# Why can't I try-with-resources in MY servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, try-catch

I have a JEE 7 servlet that sends a picture from a networked web cam to the user's browser.  If the camera is on, all is well and the image is sent.  If the camera is off, my own "DeviceUnavailableException" is thrown. The servlet then sends an alternative image indicating that the camera is off-a kind of friendly visual error message. This is the code:-

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();    // Cannot use try-with-resources here!
        Camera camera = new Camera(ip, username, password);
        byte[] vImage = camera.getEntropy();
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        System.out.println("Sending visualisation...");
        os.write(vImage);
        os.close();
    } catch (DeviceUnavailableException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        try (InputStream is = PhotonicSignalVisualisation.class
                .getResourceAsStream("unavailable.png");
                ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream()) {
            byte[] uImage = new byte[623];    // need to know exact file size of wait.png
            is.read(uImage);
            response.setContentType("image/png");
            System.out.println("Sending unavailable image...");
            os.write(uImage);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("No luck sending device unavailable image");
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

This code works.

Weird thing is that whilst I can have a try-with-resources (TWR) statement in the DeviceUnavailableException catch block, I can't in the try block at the top.  NetBeans suggests I convert to TWR, but when I do, no image is returned to the browser.  It appears that os.write(uImage) is executed, but sent elsewhere, not to the browser!

I'm probably approaching this all backwards, but I can't understand the TWR issue here.  Is there a better way to handle the friendly error situation?  I was trying to avoid a simple broken image icon on the browser when the camera is off.

Answer (score -2):

All the classes inside TWR block should implement AutoCloseable interface.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

> The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed
>   at the end of the statement. Any object that implements
>   java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all objects which implement
>   java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource.

Solution: Make your `Camera` Class implement AutoCloseable.

Comment: No.  I've done that as you suggested and it makes no difference.  It compiled before as TWR, just returned a blank image, not a java error.   It's some thing to do with scope and grabbing the output stream (os)...